# OpenFileDialog closes form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a weird error, when I try to open a filedialog it goes back to visual studio and that's it, it just closes the form.

Here is my entire code, its just a test form with 1 button on it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Week7_Oprd1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.ShowDialog();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint there? Also what is in the constructor and FormLoad for the second form?

Comment: Please post all of your code.  Also note, `ShowDialog()` is a blocking call; it requires user input.

Comment: The form closes when you press the OK (or Cancel) button on the FolderBrowserDialog?

Comment: It doesn't open the browser at all, all that it does is go back to a my code no errors nothing.
Had a friend test it on his pc and the code just worked fine.

Comment: Don't you have to add the control to the form, as with a button or label? `this.Controls.Add(tbd)`?

Comment: This could be a difference in Operating Systems, or UAC settings or something. Also I tried your edited code, worked fine for me.

Comment: You it doesn't work for me at all, I'm really confused how and why it doesn't

Comment: You never answered gunr2171's first comment, what happens if you set a breakpoint inside your button click? I just tested the same code you have, including your using statements, and it worked exactly as expected.

Comment: Nothing happens it goes to the breakpoint, I press f11 it pops back to Form1 and instantly back to the code while closing the form

Comment: I would start fresh with a brand new Visual Studio project and then enter the same code.  Should work.

Comment: tested that 3 times even tried switching to visual studio 2010, also tried restarting my pc. nothing worked

Comment: @TheUnknown, What OS are you running, and do you have UAC turn on, or any other "blocking" systems. (and I doubt this) is your anti-virus getting in the way?

Comment: I'm runnin windows 7 Home Premium and visual studio 2012 Ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after messing around with it for endless time I asked one of my teachers to help me.
The problem was that the debug was set to run with any cpu.
after setting it to x64 it worked.